# Iam not getting response from the Brainshop API i have integrated in my android app

Tags: android, chatbot

> Error: Failed to connect to api.brainshop.ai/52.**.74.**:4**

This is the error message I have received in logcat. Please help me as I am not getting where is the mistake.

I have also tried `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"` this is manifest file but still nothing happens.The API is working perfect in Postman API testing.

I am not getting response from the chatbot.